# I head written node js code but the post method is not working but get method is working, why?

Tags: html, node.js, express

html part

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Calculator</h1>
        <form action="/index.html" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="First Number">
            <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Second Number">
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Calculate</button>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

node js part

```js
const express = require("express");
    
const bP = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bP.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/",function(req,res){
    res.send("Thanks for posting that");
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("The server is started on port 3000.");
});
```

The index.html file contains two input fields taking two numbers and a submit button.
On clicking submit button I am getting output

Cannot POST /index.html

Comment: In your form are you trying to do `action="/index.html"`?

Comment: If you show relevant front end code, people will be able to help you better.

Comment: Yes, I had defined action attribute as, action = "/index.html" still app.post() is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had just correct the app.post() method

Before correction it was like this:

````
    res.send("Thanks for posting that");
});```

After correction:
```app.post("/index.html",function(req,res){
    res.send("Thanks for posting that");
});```
````